# jQuery traversal of complex array and objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, traversal

I'm having trouble traversing an array with multiple levels of objects and arrays within it. What I want is a way to pull either the keys or values of my object based on the index I provide.

```
var AllProducts =[  
    {  
        "Bottle":[  
            // Index is 0 within object,but how do I access it? 
            {
                "URLbase":"_Bottle_",
                "UniqueIdentifier":null,
                "ProductTitle":"Fitness Bottle",
                "ProductPrice":"$5.51",

            }
        ],
        "Bike":[  
            // Index is 1 within object, but how do I access it?            
            {  
                "URLbase":"_Bike_",
                "UniqueIdentifier":null,
                "ProductTitle":"Aluminum Bike",
                "ProductPrice":"$168.98",

            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I can list the values or keys of BOTH arrays with this, but it seems repetitive, and I can't find a way to access just the "Bottle" or "Bike" array objects.

```
$.each(AllProducts[0], function(index, value) {
    $.each(value, function(key, val) {
        $.each(val, function(ind, va) {
            console.dir(va);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: how about this : `AllProducts[0]['Bike'][0]` ?

Comment: I don't want to find the array Bike by it's name, but rather only its index within AllProducts.

Comment: i don't get it.

Comment: Shouldn't the arrays "Bottle" and "Bike" have respective indexes within the array of AllProducts? I can't seem to access them by those indexes but that is how I need to access them.

Comment: you mean something like this: `console.log(Object.keys(AllProducts[0]));`

Comment: I constantly have trouble accessing nested stuff and have been meaning to post a good question/answer for it but here is [one fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/nL9h0m4u/) I was working on recently to use as reference for when working with flat files. Hopefully one of them applies to your situation.